# C# Checking if list of objects contains an object with specific variable

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list that needs to have objects added or modified depending on if they already exist or not named countries. It contains Country type objects and they themselves contain a name, points and a Skier type object.

```
List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
...inputs
string name= inputData[1];

if (find if a country with name exists inside countries list)
{
   change the country
}
else
{
   make new country
}
```

I have the other stuff figured out but I dont know what to put in the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`countries.Any(c=>c.Name==name)` will return you a Boolean true if `name` exists in the list, but you might be better swapping Any for FirstOrDefault and testing the result:

```
var country = countries.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Name==name);
if(country == default)
  //add
else
  //update the properties of the `country` variable here
```

Answer (score 0):

could you use first or default to check the list. if it is not there add it.

```
if (countries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name) == null){
       countries.add(new Country{Name = name});
    } else {
      // change country
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `List<T>.Exists(Predicate<T>)` Method . Specifies whether the `List<T>` contains the specified value.

```
if(countries.Exists(a => a.Name == name))
{
    //change properties
}
else
{
    //add
}
```